# Why NSDictionary is nil?

Tags: ios, swift, nsdictionary

This is code where i am doing mistake help.

```
         for result in (result2 ){

            var dictData: NSDictionary?

             dictData?.setValue(result.valueForKey("offer_title") as? String, forKey:"offer_title")
              print(result.valueForKey("offer_title") as? String)
            if result.valueForKey("discountPercentageOff") as? String != "" {
                dictData?.setValue(result.valueForKey("discountPercentageOff") as? String, forKey:"discountPercentageOff")
                print(result.valueForKey("discountPercentageOff") as? String)
            }

            dictData?.setValue(result.valueForKey("is_booked") as? Bool, forKey:"is_booked")
             print(result.valueForKey("is_booked"))
            dictData?.setValue(result.valueForKey("is_saved") as? Bool, forKey:"is_saved")
            print(result.valueForKey("is_saved"))

            dictData?.setValue(result.valueForKey("area_id") as? String, forKey:"area_id")
            print(result.valueForKey("area_id"))

            dictData?.setValue(result.valueForKey("area_name") as? String, forKey:"area_name")

            dictData?.setValue(result.valueForKey("business_id") as? String, forKey:"business_id")
            dictData?.setValue(result.valueForKey("business_name") as? String, forKey:"business_name")
            dictData?.setValue(result.valueForKey("category_id") as? String, forKey:"category_id")
            dictData?.setValue(result.valueForKey("category_name") as? String, forKey:"category_name")
            dictData?.setValue(result.valueForKey("expiry_date") as? String, forKey:"expiry_date")
            dictData?.setValue(result.valueForKey("featured") as? String, forKey:"featured")
            dictData?.setValue(result.valueForKey("locality") as? String, forKey:"locality")
            dictData?.setValue(result.valueForKey("offer_available") as? String, forKey:"offer_available")
            dictData?.setValue(result.valueForKey("offer_id") as? String, forKey:"offer_id")
            dictData?.setValue(result.valueForKey("offer_image") as? String, forKey:"offer_image")
            dictData?.setValue(result.valueForKey("offer_nature") as? String, forKey:"offer_nature")
            dictData?.setValue(result.valueForKey("offerNatureValue") as? String, forKey:"offerNatureValue")
            dictData?.setValue(result.valueForKey("on_going") as? Bool, forKey:"on_going")
            dictData?.setValue(result.valueForKey("discountOriginalPrice") as? String, forKey:"discountOriginalPrice")
            dictData?.setValue(result.valueForKey("discountDiscountedPrice") as? String, forKey:"discountDiscountedPrice")

            let offer = Offer()
            offer.setDatafromServer(dictData!)
             self.saveOfferData(item as! NSDictionary)
            print("item:\(dictData)")

            self._featuredOfferArray.addObject(offer)
            self.feturedOfferTableView.reloadData()



        }
```

when i pass nsdictionary as param it give error optional nil, and you can see i created nsdictionary each loop. but it is yet nil. i can not understand.

Comment: You need declare a NSMutableDictionary not a NSDictionary

Comment: `NSDictionary` is not mutable.

Comment: i cahnged bu no any result

Comment: I see where you declared a reference to a `NSDictionary` but not where you created one.

Comment: Why do you create an **optional** dictionary with non-optional data?? The reason is `NSDictionary` is immutable and you never initialized the dictionary. Use a native Swift dictionary and key subscription and you get mutability for free. And stop using `setValue:forKey:` unless you know (and need) the special behavior.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 var dictData: NSDictionary?
```

Change this line to

```
 var dictData = NSMutableDictionary();
```

Answer (score 3):

You never initialize your dictionary, `var dictData: NSDictionary?` only defines what kind of type the variable will be. Also, if you want to change the dictionary, it has to be mutable.

Start with:

```
var dictData: NSMutableDictionary? = NSMutableDictionary()
```

Answer (score 0):

The failure reason is that the dictionary is not initialized at all.

There is a much easier syntax with Swift native types, any type casting is actually not needed because you're just copying `AnyObject` items. If any value is `nil` the key is not set.

```
 for result in result2  {

     var dictData = [String:AnyObject]()

     dictData["offer_title"] = result["offer_title"]
     dictData["discountPercentageOff"] = result["discountPercentageOff"]
...
```

Or even copying the entire dictionary (in Swift no problem due to value semantics) and removing the unused keys is still more efficient.